# jsPDF is not defined, because?

Tags: jspdf

My code:

```
// Gerar PDF com informações do cliente e da empresa
            $('#generatePDFBtn').click(function() {
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // Criar PDF no formato A4
                var marginLeft = 15; // Margem esquerda
                var marginTop = 15; // Margem superior
                var fontSize = 12; // Tamanho da fonte
                var lineHeight = 7; // Espaçamento entre linhas
                var tableTop = 40; // Posição superior da tabela

                // Adicionar informações da empresa
                var companyInfo = 'Nome da Empresa\nEndereço da Empresa\nCidade, Estado, CEP\nTelefone: (xx) xxxx-xxxx\nEmail: empresa@example.com';

                // Adicionar informações do cliente no cabeçalho do PDF
                var clientName = $('#clientName').val();
                var representative = $('#representative').val();
                var deadline = $('#deadline').val();
                var observations = $('#observations').val();
                var bonuses = $('#bonuses').val();
                var headerText = 'Cliente: ' + clientName + '\nRepresentante: ' + representative + '\nPrazo: ' + deadline +
                                '\nObservações: ' + observations + '\nBonificações: ' + bonuses;

                // Gerar PDF com DataTable
                doc.setFontSize(fontSize);
                doc.text(companyInfo, marginLeft, marginTop); // Adicionar informações da empresa
                doc.text(headerText, marginLeft, marginTop + 2 * lineHeight); // Adicionar informações do cliente
                doc.autoTable({
                    html: '#productTable',
                    startY: tableTop,
                    margin: { top: tableTop + lineHeight * 2 }, // Ajustar margem superior da tabela para acomodar as informações do cliente e da empresa
                    styles: {
                        font: 'helvetica',
                        fontSize: fontSize,
                        lineColor: [0, 0, 0], // Cor das linhas da tabela (preto)
                        lineWidth: 0.1, // Espessura das linhas da tabela
                        valign: 'middle', // Alinhamento vertical
                        overflow: 'linebreak', // Quebra de linha automática
                        cellPadding: 2 // Espaçamento interno das células
                    }
                });

                // Salvar ou exibir o PDF
                doc.save('orcamento.pdf');
            });
```

Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement. (novo/:254:27)
> at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:43064)
> at v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:41048)

I can't fix this error, could you help me?

I tried changing the library

Comment: how is jsPDF made available? how do you import the library?